# How to determine if you have visited an area before in a time series data

Tags: python, algorithm, geo

Currently working in python.  I have a time series data with lat/lon as coordinates.  Whats the most efficient way to determine if you are in an area you have visited before?  Ex.  In the image below, I would want to flag the 11th and 12th location because they are near location 2.  However, I would not want to flag any locations that are nearby if they are consecutive. I'd want to output something like [0, 0, 0... 1, 1, 0].

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttLWb.png

Answer (score 0):

You could store each visited coordinate inside a `dict` or a `set`, and then simply do `if coordinate in <dict or set>`,  being the variable you assigned the `dict` or `set` to. `coordinate in <dict or set>` will return True if you've already visited it, and False otherwise.

Comment: Is it possible to do this without looping through each location point?